# df.describe() wont even mention mean or percentiles

Tags: python, machine-learning

So i was trying to get some insight into my df but using describe method isnt showing the mean

Refer the image below of the outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

> For numeric data, the result’s index will include count, mean, std, min, max as well as lower, 50 and upper percentiles. By default the lower percentile is 25 and the upper percentile is 75. The 50 percentile is the same as the median.

> For object data (e.g. strings or timestamps), the result’s index will include count, unique, top, and freq. The top is the most common value. The freq is the most common value’s frequency. Timestamps also include the first and last items.

So it's likely your dataframe contains object data, or data interpreted as such.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the first row of your DataFrame contains the column names, that's why all columns are typed as object (therefore pandas does not calculate percentiles).

Try dropping the first row from df (you should probably use it to rename columns)

```
df.rename(columns={i: n for i, n in df.iloc[0, :]}, inplace=True)
df = df.drop(index=0).convert_dtypes()
```

Now it should give you percentiles IF the columns are converted to number format. Otherwise you probably have some string that prevents type conversion. Clean up the data and possibly change the type manually with:

```
df['colnameX'] = df['colnameX'].astype(numpy.float)
```